# format a full date with timezone and day of the week name string

Tags: javascript, date-parsing, date-fns

I'm trying to create a date object from the string `01:03:55.065 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021` in NodeJS javascript with `date-fns v2.21.3` but I wouldn't mind using regular javascript Date instead.

this is my code:

```
const df = require('date-fns');

const setupTime = '01:03:55.065 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021';
const ret = df.parse(setupTime,'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz EEE dd yyyy',Date.now());
console.info(ret);
```

it looks like maybe `format()` and `parse()` do not have the same formatting string ?

when I try to execute this code I get:

```
RangeError: Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `z`
    at Object.parse (/Volumes/osx-storage/projects/vocalix/parse-date-fns/node_modules/date-fns/parse/index.js:486:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/osx-storage/projects/vocalix/parse-date-fns/index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

now.. since the data that I receive will always have `GMT` in it, i tried to ignore the timezone and do:

```
const ret = df.parse(setupTime,"HH:mm:ss.SSS 'GMT' EEE dd yyyy",Date.now());
```

but this produces the output `Invalid Date`.

there is the package `date-fns-tz` but it doesn't include it's own format function so it's not relevant here.

any ideas how to resolve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this plain JavaScript solution will be helpful to you?

```js
const d = "01:03:55.065 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021";

function parseDate(s){
  const a = s.split(" ");
  return new Date([a[4],a[3],a[5],a[0]+"Z"].join(" "))
}

console.log(parseDate(d));
```

It works with the standard date constructor, accepting a string as input.

Comment: Thanks @FZs for clearing up my "non-declaration mess" - I was interrupted when posting and just wanted to put it right myself.

Comment: IMO, the code we post must be either working and correct or not working at all (if we made mistakes in it) from the first moment. Posting working code with bad practices in it is something that we should always avoid, as the OP often pastes the snippet to their codebase (erroneous code will get caught here) and ignores the updates to the answer. That way, bad practices can sneak into the askers' projects. Omitting declarations is a very common mistake that you (as a silver JS-badge owner) should know well. Pay more attention to the code you're about to post before submitting it next time.

Comment: Hey @FZs no need for the long lecture - as I said, I was in the process of clearing it up - I had a bit of a domestic crisis here and was interrupted while I was posting, hence the "unforgivable mistake". I hope we can still look eye to eye after this. ;-)
(( In the end: there were only minutes between my wrong post and me coming back for corrections. ))

Comment: I didn't want to give you a long lecture... it just became long accidentally. I wanted to express that **I find it important** that no such things are in the code we post because I saw so many projects that suffered from issues like this. So, I wanted to give a -kind of- warning to pay more attention, as this is a bit obvious mistake. Anyway, the point is that it's fixed now :)

Comment: Hey that is exactly my mission too - so, let us be civil about this. Mistakes will happen - however careful we are. And this time it _did_ happen. So: sorry for it again!